# How to use apply_along_axis to operate on parameters of objects held in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, pytorch

Setup: I have an 1d numpy array of PyTorch models, all copies of the same network. I would like to parallel train each model allow easier comparison of performance.

I currently am trying to implement this using the following:

```py
model_con = np.array([model] * sample_size)
data_con = np.array([train_data] * sample_size)
     
train_res = np.apply_along_axis(train_model, 0, model_con, data_con)
```

This kicks up a error however:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

I'm familiar with this being due to `apply_along_axis` being passed the whole arrays as opposed to the individual elements. What I am stumped to is how to get `numpy` to dig deeper into the object attributes to fix this error. Since the different model instances are independent of each other, to my understanding there should be nothing stopping this from being parallelized with a numpy array. I would very much like to avoid using a for loop in this instance, given the compute intensive nature of model training.

Comment: Show the FULL error message!,  And give us some idea of the dimensions and dtype of the arrays.  `apply_along_axis` is NOT a performance tool.  To better understand what it is doing, add a cover function to `train_model` to show what parameters are being passed to it.  Don't make any assumptions about what `apply` is doing.  Verify!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read through the guide on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This question appears to be asking about "How to train PyTorch models in parallel," perhaps reframe the question to better explain this?